# Imagick setColor not working with php

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've tried setting all pixels to black. But it isn't working. I am getting the same image as original.

Here is my code:

```php
$image = new Imagick(__DIR__."/image_new.jpg");

$i=0;
$j=0;

while ($i < 100)
{
    $j=0;
    while($j < 100)
    {
         $pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($i, $j); 
         $pixel->setColor("#000000");
         $j++;
    }

    $i++;
}

header("content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

Image size is 100x100.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the Imagick library at all, but is that the confirmed correct way to change an image's pixel colour? Do changes to an object returned by `getImagePixelColor()` actually get written back to the image? I would be surprised if it were.

Comment: I am also confused about that ! And not getting any documentation as well ! I found that it returns the ImagickPixel object. So the method setColor is of the ImagickPixel class's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Imagick::getImagePixelColor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagepixelcolor.php) will return an [ImagickPixel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickpixel.php) object; which, would have *copied* data from the originating Imagick object. After altering the pixel's data/state, you would need to "sync" the pixel back to the image. To help with this process, a [ImagickPixelIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickpixeliterator.php) object has been provided -- see [Imagick::getPixelIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getpixeliterator.php). Here's a quick example

```php
$image = new Imagick(__DIR__."/image_new.jpg");
$pixel_iterator = $image->getPixelIterator();
foreach($pixel_iterator as $i => $pixels)
{
 if( $i < 100 )
 {
  foreach($pixels as $j => $pixel)
  {
   if( $j < 100 )
   {
    $pixel->setColor("#000000");
   }
  }
 }
 $pixel_iterator->syncIterator();
}

header("content-type:image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```