# Changing pixel color value at a specific position with ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a script like this:

```
// Loop over image
$size = $im->getImageGeometry(); 
$w = $size['width']; 
$h = $size['height']; 

for ($i=0; $i<$w; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$h; $j++) {
        $pixel = $im->getImagePixelColor($j,$i);
        $color = $pixel->getColor();
        $pixel->setColor("rgb(0,0,255)");     
    }
}
```

Preferably I'd like the `setColor` command to change the color of the pixel at the specified (x,y) location, so that when I call something like:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($im->getImageBlob()).'" alt="" />';
```

An updated image will show. However, this does not work since I guess the `$pixel` was returned by value instead of by reference. It would actually be preferable if there was a `getImagePixelColor` method but I can't seem to find anything on it.

Does anyone know of a way to do this with imagemagick, or maybe recommend a library in php that can do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question, "[Imagick setColor not working with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532987/imagick-setcolor-not-working-with-php)". You'll need to initialize a [pixel iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickpixeliterator.php) to access a specific pixel, and [sync](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickpixeliterator.synciterator.php) any color changes back to the image.

```php
$image = new Imagick("someimage.png");
$pixel_iterator = $image->getPixelIterator();
foreach($pixel_iterator as $y => $pixels)
{
  foreach($pixels as $x => $pixel)
  {
   $pixel->setColor("rgb(0,0,255)");
  }
 $pixel_iterator->syncIterator();
}
```

Comment: Yea saw this a few mins ago. This is correct, although it seems as if syncing requires the entire row to be updated, so if you only want to modify one element it might be inefficient. Good to know regardless though. Thanks.